# Pandas data replace issue

Tags: python, pandas

```
Table A :
y  type
1   a
1   a
0   b
1   c
0   b
1   a
------------
Table B
type   x
 a    0.1
 b    0.2
 c    0.3
------------
```

I want to replace A.type with corresponding x in B.
Thus the result I want is:

```
y  type
1  0.1
1  0.1
0  0.2
1  0.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
A['type'] = A.type.map(B.set_index('type').x)

    y   type
0   1   0.1
1   1   0.1
2   0   0.2
3   1   0.3
4   0   0.2
5   1   0.1
```